# Distinct Unique Keys with JSON Server

Tags: javascript, json-server

I am using [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) from typicode, it works but is it possible to get requested key values as an array?

For example I have

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "ABC",
            "job": "Engineer",
            "age" : 28
        },
        {
            "name": "XYZ",
            "job": "Product Manager",
            "age" : 32
        },
        {
            "name": "ASD",
            "job": "HR Manager",
            "age" : 325
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get a array of jobs

```
["Engineer", "Product Manager", "Human Resource"]
```

Comment: Hi , welcome to SO!, while asking a questions here do share code and some of the attempts you have done to solve our issue. And also, if you have made any attempts to fix it, please edit them into your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```js
let obj = {
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "ABC",
            "job": "Engineer",
            "age" : 28
        },
        {
            "name": "XYZ",
            "job": "Product Manager",
            "age" : 32
        },
        {
            "name": "ASD",
            "job": "HR Manager",
            "age" : 325
        }
    ]
}

console.log([...new Set(obj.users.map(user => user.job))]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You can use map.

````
const data = {
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "ABC",
            "job": "Engineer",
            "age" : 28
        },
        {
            "name": "XYZ",
            "job": "Product Manager",
            "age" : 32
        },
        {
            "name": "ASD",
            "job": "HR Manager",
            "age" : 325
        }
    ]
}

display.log(data.users.map((it) => it.job))```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` to loop through the users and create a new array with the jobs:

```js
let obj = {
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "ABC",
            "job": "Engineer",
            "age" : 28
        },
        {
            "name": "XYZ",
            "job": "Product Manager",
            "age" : 32
        },
        {
            "name": "ASD",
            "job": "HR Manager",
            "age" : 325
        }
    ]
}

let arr = obj.users.map(user => user.job);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This works when I have all the data in my client. I will be paginating the data, what do I do If I want this from the server rather than filtering in the browser.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking for. Can't you just do this in Node.js (since you tagged this question with Node.js)?